# Save form v.s submit form in infopath2010

Tags: infopath

Hi 
I am new to Infopath ,SharePoint2010.

Basically , I have a form library where user can complete a form. It allows user to save incomplete form. Once they complete the form , it will allow user to submit the form. However, When saving the form , it will create new form and save into the form library ,when submit the form it will create another form in the same form library. How can I make sure that when user submit the form , it will use the current saved form.

Can this achievable or I am asking too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i understand correctly you want to assure that a new form is not generated with the updates that one will need to make or something like that.  So here is something that migth work.
1.)  Create a Custom Submit button
2.)  Add a string field that will be used to store the filename(in this case we will call field filename)
3.) Set up a series of rules on the submit button
In this case I used a three rules.  The first rule was if filename is blank set the field defined in step 2 to the value you are using for your current filename convention.  The second rule will control the submit using your current data connection.  The third rule will control your close action.
4.) Go into the data connection and make sure that you are using the value stored in the filename field defined in step 2.

Not the best wording but at least you know it is achievable.